# How to get Multiple return value From JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

I have received a string value from JSON, but when I add that JSON value to a JSON array it gives an error stating that it can not convert `String` value to `JSONArray`. Please help me.

In the response there are a 3 values in "Value"

```
protected class AsyncMenuRate extends
        AsyncTask<ForGettingRate, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(ForGettingRate... params) {
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();

        try {

            jsonObj = api.MenuRate(params[0].getTableId(), params[0].getMenulist());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("AsyncCreateUser", e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonObj;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject objects) {

        try {
            //String ss= objects.getString("Value").;
            JSONArray jarray=objects.getJSONArray("Value");
            //jarray = new JSONArray(ss);
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Successfully inserted...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is a function that I have return value:

```
String menuTotal = "0";
String item_rate;

public String MenuRate(int t_id, String menunameoflist) {
    if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed") {
        dbConnection.Open();
    }

    if (db.ChkDb_Value("select * from table_status where table_type='" + "A/C" + "'and t_id='" + t_id + "'"))
        item_rate = db.getDb_Value("select rate from menu where m_name='" + menunameoflist + "' ").ToString(); // get  the item rate from the tbl

    else if (db.ChkDb_Value("select * from table_status where table_type='" + "Non A/C" + "'and t_id='" + t_id + "'"))
        item_rate = db.getDb_Value("select non_ACrate from menu where m_name='" + menunameoflist + "' ").ToString(); // get  the item rate from the tbl

    else
        item_rate = db.getDb_Value("select driverRate from menu where m_name='" + menunameoflist + "' ").ToString(); // get  the item rate from the tbl

    //menuRate = db.getDb_Value("select menu_id From menu where m_name='" + getMenuname + "'");

    dbConnection.Close();
    return item_rate;
}
```

This is the JSON format:

```
{
    "name": "MenuRate",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "t_id",
            "type": "int32"
        },
        {
            "name": "menunameoflist",
            "type": "string"
        }
     ],
     "returnvalue": "string"
 }
```

This is function that I have get a response from JSON:

```
public JSONObject MenuRate(int t_id, String menunameoflist) throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","RestAPI");
    o.put("method", "MenuRate");
    p.put("t_id",mapObject(t_id));
    p.put("menunameoflist",mapObject(menunameoflist));
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please help me.i have also added JSON side code

Comment: How does your json look like?

Comment: "{"Value":"150"}";   like this

Comment: Ok, thats not a `jsonArray` - it's a String.

Comment: In that i have  multiple values i want to get one from that how to get It. and how to count that

Comment: You have to post your whole json into your question. How should we know how it looks like?

Comment: Please Give me a reply

Comment: You did not post your whole json and at this point no one can help you.

Comment: all code is added

Comment: And now the json format does not represent your code. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: see second post code.

Comment: i have added all code related to this function

Answer (score 0):

First your **MenuRate** method returns `String` not `JSONObject`. So you had to get that as `String` and convert it into `JSONObject`, as shown below.

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(ForGettingRate... params) {
    RestAPI api = new RestAPI();

    try {
        String jsonString = api.MenuRate(params[0].getTableId(), params[0].getMenulist());
        return new JSonObject(jsonString);
    } catch (Exception | JsonException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("AsyncCreateUser", e.getMessage());
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```

Don't forgot to add the `JsonException`, no problem some how it will ask to add the exception.

Now the string value is converted to JSON, so now you can fetch the values and while fetching use `opt` instead of `get` like `optJsonArray("key")` instead of `getJsonArray("key")` by this way we will get null value instead of exception, if the key is not present in the JSON.

Now coming to the "value" key access in your JSON response. Below is the JSON value which you have provided,

```
{
    "name": "MenuRate",
    "parameters": [{
        "name": "t_id",
        "type": "int32"
    }, {
        "name": "menunameoflist",
        "type": "string"
    }],
    "returnvalue": "string"
}
```

In your question you have mentioned that you need access a json array with the key  "**Value**". But in this there is no array with key "**Value**". So the below code will explain you how to access the "**name**" string value and "**parameters**" Json array.

```
try {
    //Name String value...
    String name = objects.optString("name");

    //Parameter Json Array...
    JSONArray parameterarray =objects.optJSONArray("parameters");

    for (int i = 0; i < parameterarray.length(); i++) {
        JsonObject jsonObj = parameterarray.optJSONObject(i);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: I dont want to get Name from json i just want to get return value of that function.

Comment: return item_rate;in this item rate i have 3 values that i have sended in android and i have also get that 3 value but i need only one value from that how to get that one value please tell me

Comment: you want one value from the json which you have posted?

If so then tell us from which key you want that one value.